# Watir - getting Watir::Heading (TypeError) while using :after selector

Tags: ruby, watir, functional-testing

I'm trying to get a particular link that is inside an unordered list. The ul element is located on the page below a h2 header with the text "Application help"

I have a watir step that has this:

```
  app_help_header = @browser.h2(:text => "Application help")

  assert @browser.link(:after? => app_help_header, :text => link_text ).exists?
```

And I am getting this error on the second line:

```
# features/step_definitions/steps_86_application_help.rb:73
expected one of [String, Regexp], got #<Watir::Heading:0x50d30c54 located=
false selector={:text=>"Application help", :tag_name=>"h2"}>:Watir::Heading (Typ
eError)
./features/step_definitions/steps_86_application_help.rb:88:in `/^I click
on "(.*?)" in Application Help$/'
features\86_Application_Help.feature:22:in `And I click on "Ordering" in A
pplication Help'
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? Is there any restriction on the kind of selectors that can be used for the :after attribute?

The documentation at http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir doesn't mention any restrictions when using `:after` as a selector.

The HTML where I'm trying to get the link is:

```
<div class="application-help-summary module">
<h2 class="portlet-section-header">Application help</h2>
    <div class="portlet-section-body">
        <p>Browse help for assistance with: </p>
        <ul class="bulleted">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/ordering-help">Ordering</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/managing-services-help">Managing services</a>
                    </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to specify to Watir: "get the link with this text that occurs after the h2 with "Application help"

As a workaround I've just specified the higher level div, and then get the link directly, specifying that the code is assuming there are no links above the "Application help" h2 with the same text.

Comment: I believe it's been deprecated/removed.  Check out http://watir.com/2012/04/24/watir-3-released/ and look for `Element#(before|after)? removed`.  Also, http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir hasn't been updated since Nov 2011, and lots has happened since then.

Comment: For watir-webdriver, I do not believe :after? was ever supported as a locator. If you share the html of your page, we can help you look for an alternative solution.

Comment: Hi Justin, I've edited the post and added the HTML that I have. It's no biggie - I've just dropped use of :after but perhaps there is a way of being more precise with the watir code (ie, link is *after* "Application help")

Comment: I think that using the parent div makes the most sense in this case. Using sibling elements as a means of locating is usually messy as it requires the use of xpath.

Comment: Note that the HTML Elements Supported by Watir page mentioned above has moved to https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/HTML-Elements-Supported-by-Watir